# Field validation using knockout

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

I need to create a validation for field using Knockout with typescript.

I need my field to by required AND it also has to be greated than 0, but only if user picks specific value from a dropdown list.

When using my code below, the message

> 'This field is required and must be greater than 0'

Pops up everytime, even with default value of the form field which is null.

Can anybody help me here? Thanks a lot

What I got so far is:

```
        self.FormData.Income.sum_others.extend({
            required: {
                onlyif: () => { return thisFormData.Income.SourceOfIncome() == 4 },
                params: true,
                message: 'this field is required'
            },
            min: {
                onlyif: () => { return this.FormData.Income.SourceOfIncome() == 4 },
                params: 1,
                message: 'This field is required and must be greater than 0'
            }
        });
```

Comment: By default knockout wants to "set" the select field value. So it acts like it's been touched and triggers the validation. Try adding the valueAllowUnset: true property to your select field. https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#using-valueallowunset-with-select-elements